# Mostrar Imagem antes de salvar no banco

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando mostrar uma imagem, antes de salvá-la no banco, em um campo image.
Segue em anexo a função que estou utilizando:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
       function mostraImagem() {
           var imagem = document.getElementById("imgImage");
           var diretorio = document.getElementById("FileUpload1").value;
           var teste = diretorio.split("\\");
           imgImage.src = teste[3];
       }
</script>
```

E aqui é o FileUpload onde chamo a função:

```html
  <asp:Label ID="Label118" runat="server" Text="Vista Anterior" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
                            <span class="ImagemAv" runat="server">            
                                <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" onChange="mostraImagem()"/><br />
                                <asp:Image ID="imgImage" runat="server" />
```

Ele não retorna erro, porém não carrega a imagem, gostaria de ao abrir o FileUpload e selecionar a imagem, ela aparecesse no campo Image, para o usuário ver a imagem, e então depois ele salvasse, a parte de salvar está funcionando já. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para exibir a imagem após ser selecionada, é possível com a API [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/FileReader):

**Exemplo:**

```js
function mostraImagem(img) {
  if (img.files && img.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var imagem = document.getElementById("imgImage");
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      imagem.src = e.target.result;
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(img.files[0]);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" ID="FileUpload1" onChange="mostraImagem(this)" /><br />
<img ID="imgImage" />
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente Lucas, Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Tenho um `package` pronto para ser utilizado (contém versão `jQuery`)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-upload-preview

Ele é basicamente o mesmo código que já foi usado como resposta.